# Will data lost when onUpgrade is called

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have created DatabaseHelper to make my development easier. If my Database version is upgrade from 1 to 2, onUpgrade will called and table will be dropped. I wonder will this cause my data stored in table dropped too? I means, will I lost my data stored in table?

Here's the code.

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your code, **Yes you will lose** the current table of the ***database*** and a new empty table `notes` will be created.

So the best way to upgrade the database is before this:

```
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
```

statement, **you should made a backup of your current database *(easiest way is to rename the table)* and then drop the current table** to create the new one.

It is always a good programming practice to keep a backup of information before editing/upgrading it.

Answer (score 2):

When you drop a table all it's data is deleted too. If you want to keep it, rename the table first, create the new one and then select the data from the old into the new one.

Comment: Nice idea to rename the table. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter table in onUpgrade method if there is change in coloumn. If you want to make fresh table then only call Drop inside onUpgrade, if there is no change in schema dont do anything inside onUpgrade method.